# Узнать связаны ли объекты по ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

Есть модели Network и ARM

```
class ARM (models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'arm'
    arm_configuration_name = models.TextField()
    arm_network = models.ManyToManyField(Network)

class Server (models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'server'
    server_name = models.TextField()
```

Задача: В шаблоне нужно вывести только те АРМ, которые связаны с Network.

Пытался сделать это в самом шаблоне:

```
            {% for net in networks %}
                <div>
                    {% for obj in net_id.arm_set %}
                        <p>{{ obj.arm_configuration_name }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Ещё пытался написать свой фильтр чтобы использовать в шаблоне. Создал файл

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from test_app.models import Network

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def arms_in_network(value):
    network = Network.objects.get(id = value)
    arms = network.arm_set.all()
    return arms'
```

Но тут другая проблема - при запуске выдаёт ошибку: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. При этом приложение прописано в settings INSTALLED_APPS. И ещё я выяснил, что эта ошибка из-за импорта Network.

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему. Буду рад если предложите другие решения.

Comment: Если кому-то интересно: AppRegistryNotReady может появиться из-за того, что вы указали приложение в INSTALLED_APPS и ссылаетесь на ту модель, которая ещё не была создана. В моём случае файл УЖЕ находился в приложении и регистрировать его было не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой шаблон:

```
{% for net in networks %}
    <div>
        {% for arm in net.arm_set.all %}
            <p>{{ arm.arm_configuration_name }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```